# Has anyone claimed that if time were infintely divisible then events would be mind depdenent?

Tags: time, infinity

Has anyone claimed that if time were infinitely divisible then events would not be mind dependent? Obviously, Zeno says something *like* this, but presumably has been refuted anyway.

Can't find anyone else, nor pin down why I might suspect that in any way at all.

Comment: A mathematical argument you may want to include into the body of the question: The probability of a point (i.e. infinitesimally small/short) event in a continuous probability distribution is defined as being zero. This means that given infinite divisibility, one could argue that at each single *point* in time the probability of *anything* is zero, i.e. nothing exists. The obvious weakness of this argument is that as soon as the qualifier "only what persists through (several points in) time, exists" is added - and this is very reasonable - existence is very much compatible with it.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking thanks for the comment, probably won't edit it in. it reminds me a little of vasabhandu's, buddhist (which i kinda know a lot more about), argument about partless parts etc., for idealism. for now, anyway

Comment: Yes, I use this argument. A true continuum has no parts therefore is not extended. Time would be conceptual and so would be all events. More or less Kant's view with a tweak. For a longer discussion you could try Hermann Weyl's 'The Continuum'. This would be the Buddhist view of time and space. I believe this is what Zeno was trying to show, that our usual idea of time is naive and incoherent.   .

Comment: Zeno's paradoxes attempt to illustrate that infinitely divisible time and space lead to movement being impossible, idk if that fits your criteria of "not real". Either way, calculus, specifically the study of infinite series, resolves his paradoxes, e.g. The geometric series 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... converges absolutely to 1.

Comment: @Not_Here Which has what to do with motion in the physical world? Nothing at all. Do you not understand the distinction between physics and math? In physics, at some point 1/n becomes indistinguishable from 0 by any physical measurement.

Comment: @user4894 "By any physical measurement" do you have a completed theory of quantum gravity that can back that up? We don't currently know if spacetime is granular or not so there is no way to justify what you just said at this moment.

Comment: At any rate, Zeno wasn't really talking about physics either. He asked a mathematical question. He said "look, if you walk a distance you first half to walk half of it, but first a quarter, but first an eighth," and so on. What bothered him, what the actual puzzle is, is that "an infinite amount of steps of finite length add up to a finite, and not an infinite, number. This shouldn't happen!" That issue is resolved after you learn some basic calculus and see that the geometric series he describes, an infinite summation of finite values, sums to a finite number, namely 1.

Comment: @Not_Here Calculus is a formalism. It's unknown whether it literally applies to the real world. In the end wouldn't that be unlikely? I don't need quantum gravity, just a freshman physics book that mentions the Planck length. Or a numerical analysis book that notes that the famous harmonic series 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + ... diverges in math, but *converges* in any physical implementation. What we can measure and compute in the physical world is not the same as what we can symbolically measure and compute in math. Math is an idealized abstraction.

Comment: @user4894 The OP asked "has anyone ever claimed x" and I gave an example of someone claiming x. You are confusing me explaining what they said with me arguing *for* what the said, because you just want to argue with me. Zeno thought he asked a physics question but it turns out what bothered him was actually the math part of it, so a math answer solved his paradox. Again, you are just trying to start an argument with me for no reason. And "I don't need quantum gravity" shows exactly how informed you are on this subject. Yes, to talk about spacetime (gravity) at small scales you need QG.

Comment: I'm not aware that Zeno has been refuted. He points out some doubtful ideas we have about time and space. One would be the idea that it is both extended and infinitely divisible. As you say, this suggests that space and time are conceptual, pace Kant and mysticism, since a real continuum would have no parts and cannot be extended. I always recommend Hermann Weyl on questions about the continuum since he seems to nail it.

Comment: @user4894 - I'm with you on this. I Like Weyl because he makes a clear distinction between the mathematical continuum and the continuum as experienced. For the most part physics uses the mathematical continuum, but the real one is what Weyl calls the 'intuitive' continuum. Zeno could be interpreted as arguing that the Weyl is right.

Comment: What do you mean by "mind dependent"? (I apologise in advance if it's a well-known technical term.) Do you mean that events might require a sentient observer, or that its outcome may vary with the observer instead of being an objective fact? Or something else altogether?

Comment: Darn it. I misread the question when commenting the first time. I would say that if time is infinitely divisible then it is a continuum. A continuum does not have parts so cannot be extended. Ergo, space-time is conceptual. But then I'd say that time cannot be infinitely divisible, since if it is then it is not divisible.

Comment: so mind depdenence is about something. e.g. fish, or rocks. we normally think both do not depend upon the mind. for them not to do so means that "rocks" could exist even without any minds around. i *think* that's pretty much the distinction, the only reason to think otherwise is that i've seen a scholar claim that it would be *absurd* for Earth exist only if there are human minds... @Lawrence

Comment: @idiotan Thanks for clarifying. Follow-up question: what is the mooted link between mind-dependence and infinitely-divisible (continuous-valued?) time? They appear, to me at least, to be quite separate concepts.

Comment: @Lawrence i'm not well versed in philosophy, it's just something i hoped might be defensible, rather than clarifiable

Comment: I think the point about mind-dependence may be that our usual (non-mind-dependent) notion of time and space is paradoxical, suggesting that they cannot exist in this way as real phenomena but must be fictional in some way. No metaphysical theory that tales space-time as naively-real works so we need not just refer to Zeno's paradoxes, there are dozens of others. A core problem seems to the our idea of infinite-divisibility, which to me is an incoherent.fudge, not a property of a continuum or a series of points. .

Answer (score 1):

If time as we (or any mechanism we construct) can observe it were infinitely divisible, the uncertainty of the energy of an object would always have to be infinite, because we would be able to observe the particle basically frozen in time.

But we have Heisenberg's inequality.  The only way to make delta E times delta t exceed h-bar over 2, if delta t can be arbitrarily small, is for delta E to be arbitrarily large.

I am not sure that makes anything 'mind-dependent', but it does mean that physical reality would not really cohere if we had this power.  So if it were really possible, everything we observe would have to be an illusion of some sort.

(But I do think we already had that result from Zeno, and from Kant's Atomicity Antinomy paraphrased by @PhilipKlocking in the first comment.  You appear to disagree.  So I am not altogether sure I understand the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Phenomonology indicates I only really have access to the Present
and it is from within this present that I remember my Past and consider
my Future.

I have to adopt the 3rd person, scientific approach to the world
to even accept time as divisible into intervals - just as space
can be divided.

Returning to the above (first person) I - where my mind occurs: 
there is no sense in which my Time (= my Present) can be
"infinitely divisible" - accepting the unity of ezperience.

Half an answer I suppose.